# Why does SortableIntField avoid UCS-16 surrogates

Tags: lucene, solr, ucs2

While reading the source code of [SortableIntField](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/schema/SortableIntField.java), I noticed that this class avoids "UCS-16 surrogates" when converting an integer to a String (see method `int int2sortableStr(int, char[], int)` of [NumberUtils.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/NumberUtils.java)).

What issue would these characters raise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments of the given code are confusing, actually there is a mistake, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Character_Set):

> Occasionally, articles about Unicode will mistakenly refer to UCS-2 as
>   "UCS-16". UCS-16 does not exist; the authors who make this error
>   usually intend to refer to UCS-2 or to UTF-16.

**Your question #1: Why does SortableIntField avoid UCS-16 surrogates?**
To decrease running time and to save space by avoiding endiness, for instance.

**Your question #2: What issue would these characters raise?**
Again, they would take [more space](http://branner.americanorientalsociety.org/dpb/publications/Branner_Surrogate_pairs.pdf) and if the endiness is an issue, then also the running time would increase. And also remember to [catch your exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew7hbz7k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), since otherwise you can put easily your server down.